# Check if object is set in VBScript

Tags: object, vbscript

Assume I create an object:

```
set newcon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

And at some point I destroy it:

```
set newcon = nothing
```

How can I tell if `newcon` is an object or nothing?

I have tried:

```
newcon is nothing
```

but I get `object required`.

If I try `isobject` or `isnull` or `isempty` it doesn't return either `true` or `false`.

Is there something else that really works?

Comment: is newcon actually defined as a variant or are you just leaving it as defined on the go?

Comment: what do you mean? if i have 'dim newcon'?

Comment: Ive always found if you dont explicitly declare variables you can end in a mess.. Option Explicit as the first line of code, then dim newcon as Variant.

Comment: same error with option explicit

Comment: If you declare it as variant rather than set it to nothing, set it to null, you can then test for null..

Comment: What do you mean when you write "if it is not in" ? Also, you really only need to set an object to Nothing when you have finished with it. The CreateObject will generate an error if it is not successful.

Comment: @BugFinder: (1) we are talking VBScript, so there is no "As-Typing" (2) mixing null (no VALUE) and Nothing (no OBJECT) is a bad idea in a language that had the bad idea of distinguish "v = value" vs. "set o = object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you accidentially changed newcon before testing it with Is Nothing:

```
>> set newcon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
>> WScript.Echo 0, IsObject(newcon)
>>
0 -1
>> set newcon = Nothing
>> WScript.Echo 1, IsObject(newcon)
>>
1 -1
>> WScript.Echo 2, newcon Is Nothing
>>
2 -1
>> newcon = "oops"
>> WScript.Echo 3, newcon Is Nothing
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
>> WScript.Echo 4, newconn Is Nothing ' oops
>>
Error Number:       424
Error Description:  Object required
```

If you get Error 434, then newcon (or the variable you really test) doesn't hold an object or Nothing.

Comment: look at your first line of your code and then compare it to mine, why is it different and why is it working for you? i really don't get that. if something is an object, can i check something else to know it size in cache or anything else compare to nothing?

Comment: Your code runs server side, mine is meant for cscript. But whether Server. or not, CreateObject() will (try to) create an object. My code proves that Is Nothing works for variables holding a nice object or Nothing; again: if your "Whatever Is Nothing" fails with error 424, then Whatever was messed up between the assignment "Set Whatever = CO()/Nothing" and the test. You could use TypeName() and/or VarType() to get further hints about the nature/state of the variable you want to test, and perhaps you should thing carefully about scope - is newcon really alive, when you test it?

Comment: @ekkhard.horner How were you able to run it in scripting prompts like that or was that just an example?

Comment: @MaximusPeters - output is from my REPL/Interactive Shell; perhaps you like Ansgar's tool (http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/2013/10/index.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

You will get an error Object required if your code resembles like

```
Dim Obj
MsgBox Obj Is Nothing
```

Here, in the above code you have not initialized Obj with any object and if you are trying to destroy an object which is not existing or initialized then obviously you will get an error "Object required" to destroy that object.

Now try below

```
Dim Obj
Set Obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Creating an object
MsgBox Obj Is Nothing 'Returns False
Set Obj = Nothing 'Destroying an object
MsgBox Obj Is Nothing 'Returns True
```

What we have done in the above code,
We have created an object using `Set Obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` statement.
Then we are verifying if object we have created is existing or not using `MsgBox Obj Is Nothing` statement. This returns 'True' as object is existing.
Now as requirement arose, we are going to disassociate i.e. destroying an object using statement `Set Obj = Nothing`.
In the last statement `MsgBox Obj Is Nothing` we are again verifying, if an object `Obj` is disassociated i.e. destroyed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is old question, however, posted answers are correct but incomplete, therefore I will post my way:

```
Dim Obj
Set Obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
If IsObject(Obj) Then
    If Not Obj Is Nothing Then
        Set Obj = Nothing
    End If
End If
WScript.Echo "Is Nothing: " & (Obj Is Nothing)
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer to explain, otherwise I would say, in my opinion, that your answer, too, is incomplete.