# How do I check if an object is set?

Tags: vbscript

I have:

```
'Set logFileObj = fso.CreateTextFile("cit.log",True)    
if logFileObj = "" then 
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj not set"
else
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj set"
end if
```

This works. Then I try:

```
Set logFileObj = fso.CreateTextFile("cit.log",True)    
if logFileObj = nothing then 
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj not set"
else
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj set"
end if
```

and I get `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`

I have replaced `if logFileObj = "" then` with `if logFileObj = nothing then`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if set object in vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849638/check-if-set-object-in-vbscript)

Comment: Wow the crows really descend on these ones quick, shame they don't flag them as duplicates as fast! How many times do you think *"How do I check if an object is set?"* has been asked over the years?

Comment: @Lankymart I literally just read that post, I have been searching for the answer for about 5-10 minutes, That post answer does not even contain an "if" statement, so it did not answer my question - and I did not infer the answer from it

Comment: Really 5 - 10 minutes? You see the section to the right that says "Related", look there second question down.

Comment: @Lankymart yes, as I said, I found that question, but I did not infer the answer from it - hence my question

Comment: The `If` is completely irrelevant the issue is using the correct syntax to check for `Nothing` which is `obj Is Nothing`. Both answers in the other question point this out.

Comment: @Lankymart well... not clearly enough for me, maybe I am a thicky, but its not clear for the way I needed to use it. So maybe I need to re-word my question to say "how do you check an object is nothing in an if statement?"

Comment: `obj Is Nothing` is simply a boolean condition it returns `True` or `False`. See [Is Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ake1y5wx(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: @Lankymart Yes, thank you, I do understand it "now" as a result of the clear and valid answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare something with `Nothing`, you must use `Is` and not `=`:

```
Set logFileObj = fso.CreateTextFile("cit.log", True)
If logFileObj Is Nothing Then
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj not set"
Else
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj set"
End If
```

This is because `=` cannot be used to compare object references in VBScript, and `Nothing` is a reference to an empty object.

See the documentation on `Nothing` for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: You should know better, this question is a obvious duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the (not-so-obvious duplicate) answer - this is much clearer then the answer from the other question - exactly what I was looking for : )

Comment: @code_fodder It's exactly the same issue, if this answer is *"clearer"* that's fine post it there not here, like I said Keith should know better.

Comment: `Nothing` is just a special object reference, `Is` compares object references to see if they are equal it's that simple.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Isobject for this as shown in the code below :-

```
if isobject(logFileObj) then
   WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj not set"
else    
   WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "logFileObj set"
end if
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. IsObject will return TRUE if the expression is an automated object. Also 2 else right after each other is not working code.

Comment: What do you mean by automated object?

Comment: You can ignore the automated. That is not the point. The point is that IsObject(logFileObj) returns true when you do set logFileObj = Nothing. Which is not was Op asked for. It only tells you if the variable is of the type object, not if it is set or not..